# how to enable some commands during run time in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have written 1 shell script to run Jstack command for a particular Process ID (PID).

But some time it may happen that multiple PIDs are there in a server for Java process.

At that case i want to run that many Jstack commands giving respective PIDs as input to the command.

Eg. If one application has 2 servers (1 tomcat and 1 jboss), then I need to run 2 JStack commands to capture 2 different logs for 2 processes.

So how to handle or check so that the script will automatically decide how many PIDs r there for java process and will run the commands written inside the script?

My script is getting all the PIDs active by

```
PID1=$(ps -ef|grep java|grep jboss| awk '{print $2}' )
```

and

```
PID2=$(ps -ef|grep java|grep tomcat| awk '{print $2}' )
```

after that I am running Jstack commands as

```
jstack $PID1 > jStack1.txt & and jstack $PID2 > jStack2.txt &
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What's the issue with above command? It's not very clear what your expectation is. If you can explain what's currently it is with sample input and what you expect in output would help.

Comment: I want the script to detect how many process IDs are there for tomcat and jboss and accordingly the jstack command should run.E.g. If only PID1 is there then jstack $PID1 > jStack1.txt & should run. If both PID1 and PID2 is there then jstack $PID1 > jStack1.txt & should run for PID1 and jstack $PID2 > jStack2.txt & should run for PID2.

Answer (score 0):

you need to combine the pids into one list and loop round them.

So something like this to get a seperate file for each pid:

```
for pid in $( ps -ef | egrep "tomcat|jboss" | awk '{print $2}')
do
    jstack $pid > jstack.$pid.txt
done
```

***Following on from your last comment***

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with the array and multiple jstack calls in the loop as it will iterate once for each pid, not give you two pids in the loop, and the $0 & $1 indices don't make sense (did you mean just 0 & 1?), and you are using $N each time but the increment for it is commented out so will stay as 0.

If you are sure there can only be two pids, one for tomcat and one for jboss, then your inital code with sleeps added would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash 
Sleep1=$1 

# sleep for the first requested time
sleep $Sleep1

# do the tomcat jstack
PID1=$(ps -ef | grep java| grep tomcat | awk '{print $2}')
jstack $PID1 > jstack.tomcat.$PID1.txt

# sleep for another 60secs
sleep 60

# do the jboss jstack
PID2=$(ps -ef | grep java| egrep "jboss|JBoss" | awk '{print $2}')
jstack $PID2 > jstack.jboss.$PID1.txt
```

If there can be multiple tomcat processes and multiple jboss processes, then you need two loops:

```
#!/bin/bash 
Sleep1 = $1 

# sleep for the first requested time
sleep = $Sleep1 

# Do all the tomcat jstacks
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep java| grep "tomcat" | awk '{print $2}')
do 
    jstack $pid > jstack.tomcat.${pid}.txt ) 
done

# sleep for another 60secs
sleep 60

# Do all the jboss jstacks
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep java| egrep "jboss|JBoss" | awk '{print $2}')
do 
    jstack $pid > jstack.jboss.${pid}.txt ) 
done
```

Or some combinations of these methods could be used depending on exactly what you are after.

Comment: @dethorpe..Ya your suggestion is working fine to get all PIDs and run the Jstack command.But one issue is there. By above command if there are 2 PIDs (1 tomcat & 1 jboss), then both the JStack commands are running at a time. But i wish to run them at different time. When I am giving sleep time before the Jstack command then both the Jstack commands are in wait. Eg. after getting the PIDs, I want the  1st Jstack to run after 60 secs the script starta adn 2nd Jstack command after 120 secs. How to do that?

Comment: if i understand correctly, you just need  to use two seperate loops, one for jboss processes, then another for tomcat (alter the egrep string accordingly in each). Then put sleeps before and between the loops as you want

Comment: I am doing everything in a single for loop. I feel that 1nd Jstack is not enabled after 60 secs the 1st Jstack starts.Code is like : #!/bin/bash

Sleep1=$1
Sleep2=$(expr $Sleep1 + 60)

N=0
for pid in $(ps -ef | grep java| egrep "tomcat|jboss|JBoss" | awk '{print $2}') ;
do
      testarray[$N]="$pid"

      (sleep Sleep1;jstack ${testarray[$0]} > jstack.${testarray[$0]}.txt )



      (sleep Sleep1;jstack ${testarray[$1]} > jstack.${testarray[$1]}.txt )

 #let "N= $N + 1" 
done

Answer (score 0):

To get the pid you can just use `pgrep` instead of `ps/grep/grep/awk`:

```
for pid in $(pgrep -f "tomcat|jboss")
do
  jstack $pid >> jStack1.txt 
done
```

Comment: ,I am doing everything in a single for loop. I feel that 2nd Jstack is not enabled after 60 secs the 1st Jstack starts.Code is like : #!/bin/bash Sleep1=$1 Sleep2=$(expr $Sleep1 + 60) N=0 for pid in $(ps -ef | grep java| egrep "tomcat|jboss|JBoss" | awk '{print $2}') ; do testarray[$N]="$pid" (sleep Sleep1;jstack ${testarray[$0]} > jstack.${testarray[$0]}.txt ) (sleep Sleep1;jstack ${testarray[$1]} > jstack.${testarray[$1]}.txt ) #let "N= $N + 1" done